# Wear OS Notification Vibration and Sound

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0, android-wear-notification

In my foreground service I get notifications and this is working totally fine. The only problem is that my watch don't vibrate or make any sound when I get a notification. I tried setting vibration on `NotificationChannel` or on `Notification` but neither works. Device is a Huawei Watch 2.

NotificationsChannels:

```
private void createNotificationChannels() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );
        serviceChannel.setDescription("Foreground Service");

        NotificationChannel messageChannel= new NotificationChannel(
                message_CHANNEL_ID,
                "messages Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );
        messageChannel.setDescription("message Channel");
        messageChannel.enableVibration(true);
        messageChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        messageChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[] {2000});


        NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(messageChannel);

    }
```

Notifications from service:

```
private void runNotification(Datamodel data)
{
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, messageChannel)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alarm)
            .setContentTitle(data.getline1())
            .setContentText(data.getline2())
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(Html.fromHtml(data.toString(), FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#009999"))
            //.setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            //.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
            //.setVibrate(new long[]{2000})
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    NOTIFICATION_ID++;

}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly the same problem and watch model. When you test the notifications, wearing the watch on your wirst instead of let it connected to the computer with cable. It works for me.